# Can I access Android calendar from web browser?

Tags: android, browser

I am trying to test something about the calendar. For example, In my web page there is a button and the js calendar will pop-up when I click the button.I choose the date and write some tasks for that day.Then I want to save the data to andriod native calendar.How can I access?

Comment: I don't think it is possible

Comment: How did you try to access? Show the code.

Comment: @vahdet it is still in idea stage.